# Sum of a gridview column in a textbox in yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I want to show the sum of a gridview column in a textbox. When the page loads, the sum should pass to the textbox.
I've written the following javascript code in my index.php file. But not getting the sum. The javascript code might not be correct. Please let me know how to do it -

index.php -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\sgledger\models\SellitemsgSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Sunglass Ledger';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="sellitemsg-index">

    <h1>Sunglass Ledger</h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <div class= 'col-md-6'>
        <?= GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'purchasetable',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel2,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'poisg_id',
            [
             'attribute' => 'Date',
             'value' => 'posg.posg_date'
            ],
            'posg_invno',
            [
             'attribute' => 'Vendor',
             'value' => 'posg.posg_vname'
            ],

            //'poisg_sgname',
            'poisg_qty',

            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
    </div>

    <div class= 'col-md-6'>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'selltable',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'ssgi_id',
            [
             'attribute' => 'Date',
             'value' => 'sellsg.ssg_date'
            ],
            'ssgi_invoiceno',
            [
             'attribute' => 'Customer',
             'value' => 'sellsg.ssg_customer'
            ],
            //'ssgi_sgname',
            //'ssgi_price',

            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
/* start getting the textboxes */
$script = <<< JS
$(document).on('ready', function(e) {

        var purgrid = purchasetable.getElementsByTagName('poisg_qty');
        var total0 = 0;


        for (var i = 0; i < purgrid.length; i++) {

            var totp = purgrid[i].value
            total0 = parseInt(total0) + parseInt(totp);
        }

        // ^ This number takes (n+1)th column
        console.log('First table total value: ' + total0);

    })
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
/* end getting the textboxes */
?>
```

Present output - 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be you can use showFooter for gridView

Firts you ca can calculate the value using the dataProvider

```
        $yourTotal =0;
        $numRow = 0;
        foreach ($dataProvider->models as $key => $value) {
            $yourTotal += $value['your_attribute'];
            $numRow++;
        }
```

Then in  GridView you can set showFooter => TRUE and in the column you need you can add footer (and eventually footerOptions)

```
        echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ......
        'showFooter'=>TRUE,
        ..... 
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ......
            [   'attribute' => 'your_attribute',
                'label' => 'Your Lable',
                'footer' => $yourTotal,
                'footerOptions' => ['style' => 'text-align:right;'],        
            ],            
            ........
```

and you can add you text using  [input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#textInput%28%29-detail)

```
<?= Html::textInput('your_name', $yourTotal , options[]); ?>
```

or you can add a simple div

```
<div id='my_id'> <?=  $yourTotal ?> </div>
```

Comment: Hi ScaiseEdge. Showfooter I can do with kartik gridview itself. But I don't actually want it. I want to pass the data to a textbox. Becasue I want to have three textboxes. 1. Purchased(from one gridview) 2 sold (from sold gridview) in the same page and 3. Stock(Difference between the first two textbox.)

Comment: @Tanmay  Hi... then  you can use the first part of my answer for calculate the value you need using dataProvider  .. and if you don't need footer you can add the value  directly using the calculated value and a single textbox..  (accessing the the value in gridTable by javascript like you are try  is not easy ... you can inspect the html resulting code for a check)

Comment: Hi ScaiseEdge.. I'm unable to make it through. Can you please post the total code.

Comment: I have update the answer but ..add an input .. si not so complex .. .

Comment: Ohh. Working fine. Another question I want to ask - please give mme the function how to count the number of rows just like counted the total?

Comment: I've added the following code to get the number of rows. but getting 0 as result. but i have 2 rows.
<?php
$numRow =0;
            foreach ($dataProvider->models as $key => $value) {
            $numRow += $numRow;
        };
?>
<?= Html::textInput('Sold', $numRow); ?>

Comment: Working fine. I have another question. I'm getting sum(column) from dataprovider1 and count(rows) from dataprovider2. Now I want to get the difference between these 2 in another textbox like before as stock = (sum(column) - count(rows)). Can you tell me or should I explain it in another question.